# rent days in month function

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm trying to create an R Function that can calculate the days rent in a month. It would have as arguments: start_date, end_date, current month. And return an integer output of rent days in month. (This will be used in context of an apartment rental model).

For example,

```
library(lubridate)

start_date <- ymd('2017-06-15')
end_date <- ymd('2018-06-14')
current_month <- ymd('2017-06-01')

rent_days_in_month(start_date, end_date, current_month)
[1] 16
```

I have a function that I think works, but it seems overly complicated. I'm also wanting to make sure this will work vectorized so I can apply on a data frame with mutate.

Here is my function:

```
rent_days_in_month <- function(start_date,
                               end_date, 
                               current_month){

  last_day_in_month <- ceiling_date(current_month,
                                    unit = "months") - 1

  current_month_days_in_moth <- days_in_month(current_month)

  first_day_in_month <- floor_date(current_month,
                                   unit = "month")

  if (last_day_in_month < start_date) {

    rent_days_in_month <- 0 

    return(rent_days_in_month)

  }

  rent_days_in_month <- as.numeric(end_date - start_date + 1)

  rent_days_in_month <- min(rent_days_in_month, 
                            current_month_days_in_moth)


  if (end_date < last_day_in_month){

    if (end_date > first_day_in_month){

      if (start_date  > first_day_in_month) {

        rent_days_in_month <- end_date - start_date - 1

        return(rent_days_in_month)

      } else {

        rent_days_in_month <- end_date - first_day_in_month

        return(rent_days_in_month)
      } 

    } else {

      rent_days_in_month <- 0 

      return(rent_days_in_month)

    }

  }

  return(rent_days_in_month)

}
```

I then tried to make it Vectorized like this:

```
v_rent_days_in_month <- Vectorize(rent_days_in_month)
```

Is there anything out there that would work simpler than this? Also, wanting to know if this the proper use of the Vectorize function.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what your function does? I'm not seeing how you arrived at `16` in your example.

Comment: The function you wrote, with the arguments you specify, spit out `30` not `16`!

Comment: Thanks Yannis, you are right! My function is not working. It's supposed to take a lease start date, lease end date, and a month to evaluate. Then it is supposed to return the applicable days of rent that will be charged. It should be 16, not 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
start_date <- as.Date("2017-06-15")
end_date <- as.Date("2018-06-14")
current_month<- as.Date("2017-06-01")

rent_days_in_month = function(start_date, end_date, current_month){
  if(month(current_month) == month(start_date) & year(current_month) == year(start_date)){
    return(as.numeric(difftime(ceiling_date(start_date, "month"), start_date, units = c("days"))))
  }else if(current_month < floor_date(start_date, "month") | current_month >= ceiling_date(end_date)){
    return("invalid date")
  }else if(month(current_month) == month(end_date) & year(current_month) == year(end_date)){
    return(as.numeric(difftime(end_date, current_month, units = c("days"))) + 1)
  }else{
    tmp = ceiling_date(current_month, "month") - 1
    return(day(tmp))
  }

}

> rent_days_in_month(start_date, end_date, current_month)
[1] 16

> rent_days_in_month(start_date, end_date, as.Date("2015-01-01"))
[1] "invalid date"

> rent_days_in_month(start_date, end_date, as.Date("2018-01-01"))
[1] 31

> rent_days_in_month(start_date, end_date, as.Date("2018-06-01"))
[1] 14
```

Comment: Kristoferson, thank you. This seems to work exactly like I am trying for! Also, do you think would work with mutate on a data.frame. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChrisKiniry I honestly have never used mutate. I took a quick look at the help file on it though and I can't see why it wouldn't work. Give it a shot and post back if it fails.

Comment: It seems to work on a data.frame with mutate if I do: v_rent_days_in_month <- Vectorize(rent_days_in_month)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
start_date <- as.Date('2017-06-15')
end_date <- as.Date('2018-06-14')
days <- seq(start_date, end_date, by= 'days')
lapply(split(days, month(days)), length)
```

Use the `seq` function with the argument by = 'days' to get a vector of all those days. Then split into a list by month and sum.